# Website upload error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi when i upload my website i get the following error

> > Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An application error
>   occurred on the server. The current
>   custom error settings for this
>   application prevent the details of the
>   application error from being viewed
>   remotely (for security reasons). It
>   could, however, be viewed by browsers
>   running on the local server machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this
>   specific error message to be viewable
>   on remote machines, please create a
>    tag within a
>   "web.config" configuration file
>   located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This
>    tag should then have
>   its "mode" attribute set to "Off".
>
> Notes: The current error page you are
>   seeing can be replaced by a custom
>   error page by modifying the
>   "defaultRedirect" attribute of the
>   application's 
>   configuration tag to point to a custom
>   error page URL.

Any one have any ideas when this is when i run the code i get no errors and the website works?

Any help at all would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.First of all show normal error for us:

> To enable the details of this specific
>   error message to be viewable on remote
>   machines, please create a
>    tag within a
>   "web.config" configuration file
>   located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This
>    tag should then have
>   its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

2.Then mb someone help you..

Answer (score 0):

The error message you posted doesn´t provide specific error details, it is masked behind a generic error message because in your web.config file the custom error settings are configured to hide the details, as the message you posted says.

You can check the application event log to see if you find the actual error. 
Also, this same question has appearently been answered already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412207/asp-net-show-error-details)

The answer may not be your answer tho, because we don´t actually know what your error is.

Hope it helps.